# Xamarin Forms : Embeded Images not loading in Windows or iOS, but work in Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

So, I started working on my very first Xamarin Forms app and I've run into a weird issue. I've followed all the dead threads, tutorials and even the official one about embedding the images.

What I have currently :

I have a PCL Xamarin.Forms app. In the PCL resources, I have added the `.png` and have made sure that the Build Action is "Embedded Resource", via the properties.
In Android, build action is set  to "AndroidResource", where as, in iOS, they're set to  "BundleResource" and for windows, it is set to "Content", as mentioned in various documentations.

I'm using these images to show up as icons in my XAML. I have a `Tabbed Layout` and in XAML, I have called these resources, along with the correct XAML files representing the pages. The weird thing is that the Icons show up in Android just fine. However, in iOS and Windows, they don't.

I even tried this code snipped to see the loaded embeded resources :

```
// NOTE: use for debugging, not in released app code!
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
}
```

The output is :

```
[0:] found resource: MyApp.MainPage.xaml

[0:] found resource: MyApp.App.xaml

[0:] found resource: MyApp.images.icon_settings.png

[0:] found resource: MyApp.images.icon_one.png

[0:] found resource: MyApp.images.icon_two.png

[0:] found resource: MyApp.images.icon_download.png
```

I've tried running this in iOS, Windows and Android, the same resources are being loaded.

Now, another weird issue. If  I refer to these images as `"MyApp.images.icon_download.png"`, Android build crashes saying that "Resource Not Found". But, Windows build just fine, but still no Icon image.

What could the issue be? I've even tried deleting all the images from iOS and Windows (From VS itself) and then added those again. But, same issue. I've even cleaned and re-built the whole solution, but same issue.

This is the XAML I've written :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
            BackgroundColor="White">
    <NavigationPage Title="One List" Icon="icon_one.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:ListOfOne />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Two List" Icon="icon_two.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:ListOfTwo />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <local:ApplicationSettingPage Title="Application Settings" Icon="icon_settings.png"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Now, there's one more weird thing. If you noticed that there's another `.png` file, named `"MyApp.images.icon_download.png"`. I'm referencing that image in another XAML as `"Image="icon_download.png"`  and putting it on a Button. That one is loading just fine on all the platforms.

I seriously have no idea what is happening here. Really need help with this.

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to where you are putting those images.  Are you putting them in the PCL as EmbeddedResources or in the Platform Projects folders?

Normally for a Xamarin Forms app you will want to put your images in each of your platform specific projects (as opposed to the PCL).  This allows you to have multiple images in different DPI Settings. Each platform handles this slightly differently. For example (iOS uses 2x, 3x folders - Android uses drawable folders).

Comment: I'm doing both. I have the resources in the PCL, as well as all the platform's respective resource folders.

Comment: You can try to only put image sources in each platform's folder. Remove the PCL folder's sources. Use image source's name directly without prefix(namespace's name).

Comment: did that, still same issue.